# Difference between AsyncListUtil and Data Paging library?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, data-paging, android-jetpack, android-paging

Android introduces a new paging library which is `Data Paging`. Previously we had the `AsyncListUtil` class which works with RecyclerView for handling asynchronous data loading.

`Data paging` also work with RecyclerView as well and doing the same task as AsyncListUtil does in addition with the architecture component related stuffs.

What's the actual difference between `AsyncListUtil` and `Data paging library` except the architecture related stuffs.

Comment: `AsyncListUtil` seems limited to position-based "paging". This works well with a database but might not with some Web services. The Paging library offers more flexibility here.

Comment: Check this for further explanation [droidcon SF 2017 - Efficient Lazy Loading for RecyclerView with Room](https://youtu.be/co1HoUKR_YQ)